# box plot to error plot conversion in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, statistics, boxplot

How can we convert a box plot generated from [image]

```
# Boxplot of MPG by Car Cylinders 
boxplot(mpg~cyl,data=mtcars, main="Car Milage Data", 
    xlab="Number of Cylinders", ylab="Miles Per Gallon")
```

to an error plot (for 25th and 75th quantile) with minimum effort? [image]

Comment: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_%28ggplot2%29/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link of @Keniajin sets you on the right track, but you will need functions for your quantiles. It's a ggplot solution:

```
require(ggplot2)
```

First, we create functions to calculate the quantiles25 en 75

```
Q25 <- function(x) {quantile(x, .25)}
Q75 <- function(x) {quantile(x, .75)}
```

Then we make the plot, using `stat_summary` and these functions. Note that you can replace the function with median, min, max of stderr if you wish.

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=cyl,y=mpg)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,fun.ymin=Q25, fun.ymax=Q75) +
  ggtitle("Car Milage Data") +
  xlab("Number of Cylinders") +
  ylab("Miles Per Gallon")
```